# How to debug JSP files with IntelliJ Idea 15 (breakpoints aren't working)

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

I'm trying to debug JSP file from Intellij Idea 15. I've put breakpoints in several places but the program still goes on.

Also, I've tried to configure the JSR45 plugin for Intellij, but it does not work because I haven't config script in my project to run it.

Does anybody know the solution for this issue? 
Feel free to share your suggestions!

Comment: I've checked that post, but It doesn't work for me as I've mentioned above about JSR45 plugin

Answer (score 1):

It does not make much sense to debug `jsp` pages if you don't put any scriptlets or javascript.

- If you used `java` code in `jsp` pages, **don't debug,** just  **¡¡DELETE IT!!**.
- If you want to debug the `javascript` code use your browser inspect and put debug points there or between the code using `debugger;`

Comment: Actually, I agree with you that code should be deleted, but while `javascript` UI is in the development phase, we are working with a legacy of `JSP` mess. It uses  `JSTL`, so I want to check `<div class="header">
                    <c:set var="pureGP" value="${year.pureGP}"/>` code example replaces by correct value

Comment: Not sure if/how you can debug the render of the page, but you will see this info in the rederized html when this variable is used